# R - Export Numsummary to csv

Tags: r, csv

I'm having some trouble exporting some information from R.
The information is a numsummary, I can get most of the summary into a csv using the suggestion [linked here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/basic-statistics-to-csv-td831570.html#a831572) which is basically just

```
write.csv(numsummary$table)
```

but every time I use this the last column gets cut off from the csv output.

I haven't been able to find a way to get the last column included in csv output, would anyone know how to do this or be able to point me to a resource I could check to find out how to do this?

Please let me know if there's any more information I could provide that would be helpful, and thanks in advance for your help!

edit: complete R-script of an example where the last column - in this case the column headed 'n' - is cut off. Using csv.write(input$table) seems to leave the last column out on any type of output I use, not just numerical summaries.

```
#start toothGrowth csv generation
#dataset available at https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/ToothGrowth.csv

toothGrowth <- read.table("ToothGrowth.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
numSumTooth <- numSummary(toothGrowth[,c("dose", "len", "X")], statistics=c("mean", "sd", "IQR", "quantiles"), quantiles=c(0,.25,.5,.75,1))
str(toothGrowth)
numSumTooth
write.csv(numSumTooth$table, file="numSumTooth.csv")

#end toothGrowth csv generation
```

The output I generate using the script above is linked here on pastebin [sumSumTooth](https://pastebin.com/TSEL0unk)

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example to your issue. I have no issue with exporting `numSummary` on my test.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Adam, I've added a script that reproduces the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why "n" was missing is because that value is kept as `numSummaryObj$n`, while the other exploratory values are kept as `numSummaryObj$table`.

Putting it back requires a simple `cbind` or `data.frame` command:

```
file <- "https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/ToothGrowth.csv"
toothGrowth  <- read.table(file, header=T, sep=",", row.names=1, na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

numSumTooth <- RcmdrMisc::numSummary(toothGrowth[, c("len", "dose")])

nST <- data.frame(numSumTooth$table, numSumTooth$n)
names(nST) <- c(colnames(numSumTooth$table), "n")

write.csv(nST, "numSumTooth.csv")
```

==

EDIT:

I would personally invest sometime in data-handling with packages like `dplyr` and `tidyr`, as they give you a lot of mileage and flexibility in future. For instance, in order to generate the same numSummary in a data.frame, you can run the following:

```
toothGrowth %>% 
  select(-supp) %>% 
  gather(var, val) %>% #convert the wide data frame into the long-form, with var = dose and len
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(val), sd = sd(val),
            IQR = IQR(val),
            `0%`= min(val),
            `25%` = quantile(val, 0.25),
            `50%` = median(val),
            `75%` = quantile(val, .75),
            `100%` = max(val),
            n = n())


# A tibble: 2 × 10
    var      mean        sd   IQR  `0%`  `25%` `50%`  `75%` `100%`     n
  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1  dose  1.166667 0.6288722   1.5   0.5  0.500  1.00  2.000    2.0    60
2   len 18.813333 7.6493152  12.2   4.2 13.075 19.25 25.275   33.9    60
```

The added flexibility in this approach is that you can choose to find mean for each group (like `supp` in this case):

```
toothGrowth %>% 
#  select(-supp) %>% 
  gather(var, val, -supp) %>% 
  group_by(supp, var) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(val), sd = sd(val),
            IQR = IQR(val),
            `0%`= min(val),
            `25%` = quantile(val, 0.25),
            `50%` = median(val),
            `75%` = quantile(val, .75),
            `100%` = max(val),
            n = n())


Source: local data frame [4 x 11]
Groups: supp [?]

    supp   var      mean        sd   IQR  `0%`  `25%` `50%`  `75%` `100%`     n
   <fctr> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
 1     OJ  dose  1.166667 0.6342703   1.5   0.5  0.500   1.0  2.000    2.0    30
 2     OJ   len 20.663333 6.6055610  10.2   8.2 15.525  22.7 25.725   30.9    30
 3     VC  dose  1.166667 0.6342703   1.5   0.5  0.500   1.0  2.000    2.0    30
 4     VC   len 16.963333 8.2660287  11.9   4.2 11.200  16.5 23.100   33.9    30
```

==

Another alternative (if you feel that writing the long summarise syntax repeatedly is a chore) is to create a function, e.g.:

```
checkVar <- function(varname, data){
  val <- data[, varname]
  tmp <- data.frame(mean = mean(val), 
                    sd = sd(val),
                    IQR = IQR(val),
                    `0%`= min(val),
                    `25%` = quantile(val, 0.25),
                    `50%` = median(val),
                    `75%` = quantile(val, .75),
                    `100%` = max(val),
                    n = length(val)) 
  names(tmp) <- c("mean", "sd", "IQR", "`0%`", "`25%`", "`50%`", "`75%`", "`100%`", "n")
  rownames(tmp) <- varname
  return(tmp)
}
```

Executing the custom function would give you summary statistics:

```
checkVar("dose", ToothGrowth)


         mean        sd IQR `0%` `25%` `50%` `75%` `100%`  n
dose 1.166667 0.6288722 1.5  0.5   0.5     1     2      2 60
```

And putting them into a single data.frame involves an apply function, e.g. with `lapply`:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c("dose", "len"), checkVar, data=ToothGrowth))


          mean        sd  IQR `0%`  `25%` `50%`  `75%` `100%`  n
dose  1.166667 0.6288722  1.5  0.5  0.500  1.00  2.000    2.0 60
len  18.813333 7.6493152 12.2  4.2 13.075 19.25 25.275   33.9 60
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, elaborating over the previous answer

I had a summary

```
str(resumenDatos)

List of 4
 $ type      : num 4
 $ table     : num [1:514, 1:8] 3.7544 4.5779 4.135 -1.0582 -0.0789 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ Group    : chr [1:514] "2020_02_28_00" "2020_02_28_01" "2020_02_28_02" "2020_02_28_03" ...
  .. ..$ Statistic: chr [1:8] "mean" "0%" "25%" "50%" ...
 $ statistics: chr [1:2] "mean" "quantiles"
 $ n         : num [1, 1:514] 2948 1784 1756 1306 1064 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "whatIWantToMeasure"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:514] "2020_02_28_00" "2020_02_28_01" "2020_02_28_02" "2020_02_28_03" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "numSummary"
```

And I created the dateFrame as follows:

```
> resumenDatosDF <- data.frame(resumenDatos$table,t(resumenDatos$n))

> names(resumenDatosDF) <- c(colnames(resumenDatos$table), "n")

> str(resumenDatosDF)
'data.frame':   514 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ mean: num  3.7544 4.5779 4.135 -1.0582 -0.0789 ...
 $ 0%  : num  -986 -997 -995 -996 -986 -997 -996 -997 -996 -997 ...
 $ 25% : num  3 3 4 13 17 15 13 3 3 3 ...
 $ 50% : num  14 21 17 24 26 26 25 15 15 13 ...
 $ 75% : num  24 30.2 27 28 28 ...
 $ 90% : num  30 37 31 32 31.7 ...
 $ 99% : num  38 49 38 40 39 ...
 $ 100%: num  250 416 105 57 214 ...
 $ n   : num  2948 1784 1756 1306 1064 ...

> head(resumenDatosDF,10)
                     mean   0% 25% 50%   75%  90%   99% 100%    n
2020_02_28_00  3.75440977 -986   3  14 24.00 30.0 38.00  250 2948
2020_02_28_01  4.57791480 -997   3  21 30.25 37.0 49.00  416 1784
2020_02_28_02  4.13496583 -995   4  17 27.00 31.0 38.00  105 1756
2020_02_28_03 -1.05819296 -996  13  24 28.00 32.0 40.00   57 1306
2020_02_28_04 -0.07894737 -986  17  26 28.00 31.7 39.00  214 1064
2020_02_28_05  3.26701571 -997  15  26 28.00 32.0 39.55   87 1146
2020_02_28_06  4.92619392 -996  13  25 28.00 31.0 39.00   59 1382
2020_02_28_07  1.13968101 -997   3  15 27.00 30.0 40.32  240 2069
2020_02_28_08 -1.99729973 -996   3  15 27.00 31.0 40.00  376 2222
2020_02_28_09  0.59954083 -997   3  13 23.00 33.0 41.52 1086 3049
```